# TempData not retaining value in FileContentResult

Tags: c#, tempdata, filecontentresult

I have the following code:

```
    [Authorize]
    [HttpGet]
    public FileContentResult DownloadMsgAsPdf(string FileId, string outer = "")
    {
        var Results = (SearchResult)TempData["Results"];
        var msg = Results.emails[FileId];
...
        return File(pdfBytes, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, msg.Id + ".pdf");
     }
```

Now upon running it once (clicking a link) it does everything completely fine. However upon clicking it a second time (with nothing else changed or called) it errors out, with Results being null. I assume this means TempData is getting cleared, but how could this be?

Here is the full code if it's needed:

```
    [Authorize]
    [HttpGet]
    public FileContentResult DownloadMsgAsPdf(string FileId, string outer = "")
    {
        var Results = (SearchResult)TempData["Results"];
        var msg = Results.emails[FileId];

        TempData.Keep();

        msg.BodyHTML = System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(msg.BodyHTML);

        var htmlContent = String.Format("<center><p><b>Case ID</b>: " + msg.Id
        + "   <b>User ID</b>: " + Session["userid"]
        + "   <b>Privileged</b>: ");
        if (msg.Tags != null)
        {
            htmlContent += msg.Tags.ContainsKey("privileged");
        }
        else
        {
            htmlContent += "False";
        }
        htmlContent += "   <b>Downloaded</b>: " + DateTime.Now.ToString("g") + "</center>"
        + " <p> -- Forwarded message -- </p> "
        + " <p><b> From :</b> <a href='#'>" + msg.From + "</a> </p> "
        + " <p><b> Date:</b> Mon, oct 25 2010 at 4:42 PM  </p> "
        + " <p> <b>Subject:</b> " + msg.Subject + " </p> "
        + " <p><b> To:</b> " + msg.To + " </p> "
        + " <p><b> Cc: </b> </p> "
        + " <div> "
        + " <ul> ";
        if(msg.attachementList != null){
            if (!msg.attachementList.Any())
            {
                htmlContent += "<text> "
                + "<li><label style='color:gray'>No attachment</label></li></text>";
            }
            else
            {
                foreach (var attachment in msg.attachementList)
                {
                    var filename = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(attachment);
                    htmlContent += "<text> "
                    + "<li><a href='#'>" + filename + "</a></li></text>";
                }
            }
        }
        htmlContent += "</ul>"
        + "</div>"
        + "<div padding: 5px;'>"
        + msg.BodyText
        + "</div>"
        + "</div>";

        var pdfBytes = (new NReco.PdfGenerator.HtmlToPdfConverter()).GeneratePdf(htmlContent);

        if (outer != "")
        {
            return File(pdfBytes, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, msg.Id + ".pdf");
        }

        return new FileContentResult(pdfBytes, "application/pdf");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`TempData` means you only can get once. And i see you use `TempData.Keep()`, but this method only effect on the same http context. I think you can use `Session` or `Cache` instead of the `TempData`.

Comment: Thanks for the response, is there any way I can use it more than once? 

I tried Session and got the same error.